# Segmentation fault with Lucene and MMapDirectory

Tags: lucene, segmentation-fault

we are using NIOFSDirectory instead of MMapDirectory in an intensive test load for indexing.  But we are still getting a SIGSEV with MMapDirectory.  Is there anything else I should be looking for? This is a Linux 64 bit machine. Head of the stack trace follows:

Please let me know what more info would be helpful.

Thanks...

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaab285ea7, pid=2408, tid=1128642880
>
> JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed >oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   J  org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput.readByte()B

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely closing your IndexReader while other threads are still using it?

Lucene tries to catch this mis-use but it's detection is best-effort only.

You could also try calling MMapDirectory.setUseUnmap(false) to turn off unmapping; this should prevent the SIGSEGV.